# Visual Studio добавить файл

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Всем привет. У меня в проекте есть `#include <float.h>`, но таких файлов у меня два - с одинаковым названием, но разным содержимым, конечно же:

1. ThirdPart/STLport/float.h
2. Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include/float.h

Из проекта видно 1-й, а мне нужен, естественно, 2-й. Можно его как-то подключить в проект, чтобы он тоже был виден?

Comment: или задавать полный путь для файла `float.h` или в проект `STLport` записывать пути по-короче. И тогда инклуды будут такими : `"STLport/float.h"` , `"float.h"` *(VC/include/)*

Comment: В проекте не должно быть двух стандартных библиотек, удаляйте STLport (зачем он вообще нужен в VS?) ну или отказывайтесь от стандартной библиотеки VS.

Comment: Указывая полное имя файла, например. Только вы уверены, что они между собой не будут ссориться?... Вернее, их содержимое?

Comment: @Harry Указать имя напрямую не получается, т.к. `#include <float.h>` в другой ThirdParty. Пожалуйста, не спрашивайте почему. Пробую добавить в проект путь к `VC/include`, но ошибка `'undefined identifier'` (который указан в `VC/include/float.h`) всё равно остается. Удалить из путей STLport также безполезно.

Comment: *"Пожалуйста, не спрашивайте почему."* - ну уж нет, если уж вы собираетесь загонять осу под шкаф, то извольте подробно расписать, зачем это понадобилась, так как с большой долей вероятности нет никакой необходимости это делать.

Comment: Не используйте угловые скобки, используйте двойные кавычки при указании путей...

Comment: @user7860670 Есть проект Converter. В нем используется `ThirdParty/STLport` и движок `ThirdParty/Mozilla`. В новой версии движка используется `_FPCLASS_NZ`, которое из `Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include/float.h`. А есть еще `ThirdParty/STLport/float.h`. И вот новый движок никак не может увидеть `Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include/float.h`. Вроде добавлен путь к нему в настройках. Изменить строку `#include <float.h>` я не могу, т.к. ThirdParty. Надо как-то в настройках это прописать, наверное.

Comment: Ну вот. Если в новой версии движка используется стандартная библиотека VS, то вам следует избавиться от STLport.

Answer (score -1):

Если вы хотите добавить в проект существующий файл - сделайте это:

> 1: Откройте обозреватель решений (ctrl + alt + l на visual studio
> 2019).
>
> 2: ПКМ по проекту/"папке" в проекте (НЕ решению).
>
> 3: Добавить -> сущ. элемент.
>
> 4: Найдите файл и нажмите "Добавить".